# How much does it cost to depend a transaction to another one?

Tags: bitcoind, api, unconfirmed-transactions

How I can depend on a transaction to an unconfirmed transaction?

How much does it cost?
Do I need to use a specific API or application?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean to "depend on a transaction"? To create a transaction that is child of another?

Comment: See OP's [previous question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/115262/13866) for clues to what OP might mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can depend on a transaction to an unconfirmed transaction?

In order for a transaction to "depend" on an unconfirmed transaction is simply the act of creating and broadcasting a transaction that uses UTXOs that are unconfirmed and not yet in a block. Most wallets don't let you do this.

> How much does it cost?

There are a lot of factors that can affect the cost of a transaction, but assuming you aren't doing anything weird the cost of the transaction should be roughly the same as any other transaction.

> Do I need to use a specific API or application?

I don't believe API's will let you do this... The action you are describing is usually done by developers who build the raw transactions to test wallets and other cases.